# Elasticsearch need to search from multiple types with type specific where clause

Tags: search, elasticsearch, nest

I have Es index with multiple type and each type caters it's own filter parameters. Now we are building a Global Search on Es for multiple type and I am bit confused how to use type specific where clause to be included in NEST.
Elastic Search
-> Type 1 (where x=1)
-> Type 2 (where y=1)

Now we are building a search query

```html
var result = client.Search<ISearchDto>(s => s
                .From(from)
                .Size(PageSize)
                .Types(lstTypes)
                .Query(q => q.QueryString(qs => qs.Query(query)))
                );
```

*lstTypes will have Type 1 and Type 2

Now how can i add the where clause for all type 1 items with x=1 and for all type 2 items with y=1 in NEST.

Hope the question is clear, any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can query on the `_type` meta field in much the same way as you query on any other field. To perform different queries based on type within one search query, you can use a `bool` query with multiple clauses

```
client.Search<ISearchDto>(s => s
    .From(from)
    .Size(pageSize)
    .Type(Types.Type(typeof(FirstSearchDto), typeof(SecondSearchDto)))
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Should(sh => sh
                .Bool(bb => bb
                    .Filter(
                        fi => fi.Term("_type", "firstSearchDto"),
                        fi => fi.Term(f => f.X, 1)
                    )
                ), sh => sh
                .Bool(bb => bb
                    .Filter(
                        fi => fi.Term("_type", "secondSearchDto"),
                        fi => fi.Term(f => f.Y, 1)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

We have a `bool` query with 2 `should` clauses; each `should` clause is a `bool` query with the conjunction of 2 `filter` clauses, one for `_type` and the other for the property to be queried for each type, respectively.

NEST supports operator overloading so this query can be written more succinctly with

```
client.Search<ISearchDto>(s => s
    .From(from)
    .Size(pageSize)
    .Type(Types.Type(typeof(FirstSearchDto), typeof(SecondSearchDto)))
    .Query(q => (+q
        .Term("_type", "firstSearchDto") && +q
        .Term(f => f.X, 1)) || (+q
        .Term("_type", "secondSearchDto") && +q
        .Term(f => f.Y, 1))
    )
);
```

Both produce the following query

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_type": {
                    "value": "firstSearchDto"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "x": {
                    "value": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_type": {
                    "value": "secondSearchDto"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "y": {
                    "value": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```